# Java Agent wont load into JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Im trying to load a Java Agent into a running JVM. I have the JVMs PID but whenever I try to load the agent into the JVM I get the error `com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute`. Both files are in the same directory. I compile the class and package the class into a JAR archive using `javac JavaAgent.java` and `jar cmf manifest.txt JavaAgent.jar *.class`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**AgentInstaller**

```
package com.company;
import com.sun.tools.attach.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AgentLoader {

    public static void loadAgent() {
        String agentPath = "JavaAgent.jar";

        System.out.println("Dynamically loading java agent");
        String pid = "9484";

        try {
            VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
            vm.loadAgent(agentPath);
            vm.detach();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaAgent**

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

class JavaAgent {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void agentmain (String args, Instrumentation inst){
        System.out.println("Java Agent inserted");
    }

}
```

**Manifest.txt**

```
Main-Class: com.company.MyMainClass
Agent-Class: com.company.AgentLoader
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to apangin I am now able to load the agent but it fails to initialize `com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize`. I am running a Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the full absolute path in `agentPath`.

Manifest should be named `MANIFEST.MF`

`Agent-Class` should be the fully qualified class name of the agent: `com.company.JavaAgent`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped resolve the issue in regards to loading but now it wont initialize. `com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize`

Answer (score 1):

This error (Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize) does not provide enough information to see where your agent throws exception. **The full stacktrace appears on the other side** - the JVM you are trying to attach to.

Attach the agent to some JVM which will display the agent output. 
Easy option is `kotlinc` (Kotlin compiler - its console waits in interactive mode). Then attach the agent and the stacktrace will appear in the kotlinc console.
Close the target JVM **before doing another attempt** with modified agent. Otherwise the changes will not be applied.